# DataGrid и SQLite Database

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, .net-4.0, sqlite

Создал БД, прикрутил ее к DataGrid вот так:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var sqlConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source = Database.db; Version = 3");
        sqlConnection.Open();

        var sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select * from List", sqlConnection);
        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        var dataTable = new DataTable("List");
        var sqlAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;
        sqlAdapter.Update(dataTable);
    }
```

Тут вроде все работает. Загружает данные из БД и отображает в DataGrid.
Но как теперь сохранять изменения сделанные в DataGrid в БД?
Вот собственно сам проект: http://rghost.ru/6rNDPDXrB

Comment: @zokizotup, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Для этого надо определить следующие свойства dataAdapter:

```
InsertCommand - для операций вставки новых строк;
UpdateCommand - для изменения существующих строк;
DeleteCommand - для удаления строк.
```

Существует объект SqlCommandBuilder, который автоматом определит эти свойства на основании значения свойства SelectCommand и при условии выборки данных из одной таблицы.

```
//Автоматически сформируем команды обновления данных 
SqlCommandBuilder =  new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlAdapter);
```

НО! если наш SelectCommand выбирает данные из двух и более таблиц придется определять InsertCommand, UpdateCommand и DeleteCommand вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Руками, всё руками. Вы ж решили не пользоваться ORM и реализовывать всё на голом SQL? Ну тогда и обновлять данные точно так же вручную.

**Обновление**

Да, так и есть. Вам придётся подписаться на изменение данных пользователем, и в нужный момент (когда именно — решать вам; например, сразу) записывать изменённые данные назад в таблицу.

А насчёт ORM почитайте, очень упрощает жизнь. Если пишете на .NET, смотрите в сторону Entity Framework. Или NHibernate.

Comment: На самом деле я никогда не работал с базами данных, и понятие ORM мне не знакомо :)
Значит нужно вручную отслеживать, в какой ячейке в DataGrid были сделаны изменения и записывать эти изменения в БД? Я вас правильно понял? Есть ли способ автоматизировать этот процесс? Сделать двусторонний байдинг к DataGrid или как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

примерно так

---

```
       SQLiteCommandBuilder cmd = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter)
               ...
    DataGrid1.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;

}

    //Save to Base
    private void updateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
          sqlAdapter.Update(((DataView)DataGrid1.ItemsSource).Table);
     }
```